# Create menu from multiple meals relationship

Tags: database-design, schema

I have the following relations:

`Meals(meal_id, name, cuisine, ingredient)`

`Users(user_id, name, username, password, email)`

`Chefs(chef_id, name, username, password, email)`

*I want to create the following relation and schema*: a relation that create menus from multiple meals for different users

Also, user can use menus that created by chefs.

I tried the `menus(menu_id, name)` and put `menu_id` attribute into Meals. it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a menus table as you've specified (albeit with a user_id field), so `menus(menu_id, user_id, name)`

I would then include a linker table to join a meal to a menu, seeing as a menu can have multiple meals and a meal can belong to multiple menus `meal_menu(menu_id, meal_id)`

**EDIT**

As Colin 't Hart suggests, for the second part of the question I would also have the chef and user share a common table (probably called `users`) as they're sharing fields. You could then have a `roles` table that links each user to a role (chef, diner etc.)

That way, there's only one link from any type of user to a menu.

Comment: And the primary key of a "meal_menu" is (menu_id, meal_id). A surrogate key can also be added, if that's your personal preference. If doing so, then the primary key will be the surrogate key, while you should add a unique key on (menu_id, meal_id) to prevent adding a meal to a menu multiple times.

Comment: Not quite there with the second requirement: "Also, user can use menus that created by chefs"... One way to do this would be to make Users and Chefs have the same group of IDs via a common parent or by having Chefs as a child of Users to identify which Users are also Chefs. Then Menus would refer to that common parent or the Users which also include Chefs. Which approach you choose depends on your requirements.

Comment: Ah, missed that part of the question!